# Cannot install android device in VS2015 Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install android device XXHDPI Lollipop.
My OS is Windows 10 Pro, and VS version is 2015.
[image]

but here is an error.

And it is a log file.

```
2015-07-31 PM 6:09:41: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 6:09:41: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 2 Platforms: 1
2015-07-31 PM 6:09:41: [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 6:09:42: [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 30 Platforms: 4
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:07: [Informational] Waiting to uninstall device...
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:07: [Informational] Uninstalling Device: 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:07: [Informational] Uninstalling virtual machine for 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:12: [Informational] Removing device files
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:12: [Informational] Uninstall complete
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:12: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:12: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 1
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:20: [Informational] Waiting to uninstall device...
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:20: [Informational] Uninstalling Device: 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:20: [Informational] Uninstalling virtual machine for 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:23: [Informational] Removing device files
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:24: [Informational] Uninstall complete
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:24: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 6:10:24: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 1
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:32: [Informational] Waiting to install device...
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:32: [Informational] Installing Device: 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone , Version: 1.0.50701.1
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:32: [Informational] Downloading and installing prerequisites
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:33: [Informational] Installing Platform: Lollipop (API 22), Version: 1.0.50701.1
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:33: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22)
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:33: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 1 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:34: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 2 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:34: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 3 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:34: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 4 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:35: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 5 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:35: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 6 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:35: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 7 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:36: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 8 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:36: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 9 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:36: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 10 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:37: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 11 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:37: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 12 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:38: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 13 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:38: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 14 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:38: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 15 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:39: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 16 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:39: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 17 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:39: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 18 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:40: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 19 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:40: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 20 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:40: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 21 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:41: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 22 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:41: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 23 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:41: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 24 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:42: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 25 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:42: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 26 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:42: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 27 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:43: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 28 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:43: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 29 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:43: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 30 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:44: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 31 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:44: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 32 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:44: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 33 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:45: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 34 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:45: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 35 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:46: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 36 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:46: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 37 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:46: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 38 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:47: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 39 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:47: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 40 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:47: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 41 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:48: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 42 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:48: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 43 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:48: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 44 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:49: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 45 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:49: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 46 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:49: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 47 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:50: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 48 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:50: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 49 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:50: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 50 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:51: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 51 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:51: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 52 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:51: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 53 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:52: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 54 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:52: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 55 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:52: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 56 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:53: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 57 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:53: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 58 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:54: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 59 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:54: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 60 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:54: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 61 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:55: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 62 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:55: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 63 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:55: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 64 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:56: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 65 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:56: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 66 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:56: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 67 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:57: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 68 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:57: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 69 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:57: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 70 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:58: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 71 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:58: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 72 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:58: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 73 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:59: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 74 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:59: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 75 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:11:59: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 76 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:00: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 77 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:00: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 78 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:00: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 79 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:01: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 80 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:01: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 81 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:01: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 82 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:02: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 83 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:02: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 84 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:03: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 85 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:03: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 86 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:03: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 87 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:03: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 88 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:04: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 89 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:04: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 90 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:04: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 91 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:05: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 92 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:05: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 93 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:05: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 94 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:06: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 95 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:06: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 96 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:06: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 97 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:07: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 98 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:07: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 99 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:08: [Informational] Downloading Lollipop (API 22): 100 %
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:11: [Informational] Installing platform files
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:39: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:39: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:39: [Informational] Creating device configuration
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:40: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:40: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
2015-07-31 PM 6:12:40: [Informational] Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:28: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:29: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:29: [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:30: [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 30 Platforms: 4
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:36: [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:36: [Informational] Launching Device: 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:36: [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:36: [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
2015-07-31 PM 9:46:36: [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:08: [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone' device.
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:08: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:08: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5.1\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 3072 /diagonalSize 5.1 /video "1440x2560" /vhd "C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5.1_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone.h" /noStart /silent
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:08: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: 13
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:36: [Informational] Waiting to uninstall device...
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:36: [Informational] Uninstalling Device: 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:36: [Informational] Uninstalling virtual machine for 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:38: [Informational] Removing device files
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:38: [Informational] Uninstall complete
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:38: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 9:47:38: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:02: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:02: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:02: [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:02: [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 30 Platforms: 4
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:56: [Informational] Waiting to install device...
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:56: [Informational] Installing Device: 5.5" KitKat (4.4) HDPI Phone , Version: 1.0.50701.1
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:56: [Informational] Creating device configuration
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:57: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:57: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
2015-07-31 PM 9:48:57: [Informational] Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine
2015-07-31 PM 9:49:35: [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5.5" KitKat (4.4) HDPI Phone' device.
2015-07-31 PM 9:49:35: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
2015-07-31 PM 9:49:35: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5.5\" KitKat (4.4) HDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5.5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5.5_KitKat_(4.4)_HDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5.5-inch KitKat (4.4) HDPI Phone.h" /noStart /silent
2015-07-31 PM 9:49:35: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: 13
2015-07-31 PM 10:04:48: [Informational] Waiting to uninstall device...
2015-07-31 PM 10:04:48: [Informational] Uninstalling Device: 5.5" KitKat (4.4) HDPI Phone
2015-07-31 PM 10:04:48: [Informational] Uninstalling virtual machine for 5.5" KitKat (4.4) HDPI Phone
2015-07-31 PM 10:04:50: [Informational] Removing device files
2015-07-31 PM 10:04:50: [Informational] Uninstall complete
2015-07-31 PM 10:04:50: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-07-31 PM 10:04:50: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
2015-08-01 AM 10:43:45: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-08-01 AM 10:43:45: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
2015-08-01 AM 10:43:46: [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2015-08-01 AM 10:43:46: [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 30 Platforms: 4
2015-08-01 AM 10:45:21: [Informational] Waiting to install device...
2015-08-01 AM 10:45:21: [Informational] Installing Device: 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone , Version: 1.0.50701.1
2015-08-01 AM 10:45:22: [Informational] Creating device configuration
2015-08-01 AM 10:45:22: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2015-08-01 AM 10:45:22: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
2015-08-01 AM 10:45:23: [Informational] Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine
2015-08-01 AM 10:46:30: [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone' device.
2015-08-01 AM 10:46:30: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
2015-08-01 AM 10:46:30: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5.1\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 3072 /diagonalSize 5.1 /video "1440x2560" /vhd "C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5.1_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone.h" /noStart /silent
2015-08-01 AM 10:46:30: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: 13
```

What should i do?

Is it crash with Hyper-V machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: error 13 = ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT (The media is write protected). Make sure path **C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd** has the permissions to write data into it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm sorry, How can i set this permissions? in File exploer?

Comment: yeah, go to folder properties->Security

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? having exactly same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I've been looking at doing to fix mine.  Credit has to go to this post though. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3)

1) Repair Android SDK - go to Programs and Features > Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android > Change and hit "Repair"

2) Remove All Hyper-V virtual switches - go to Hyper-V > Virtual switch manager > Remove all virtual switches

3) Run XdeCleanup.exe - In my case: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0"

4) In my case I had configured Internet connection sharing on Ethernet adapter before so I had to disable it

Answer (score 0):

I also could not get the emulator installed because I had disabled Hyper-V to run VMWare.  Once I re-enabled it the installation worked.