# Visual Studio Emulator for Android - An internal virtual network switch is required for emulated devices to run

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v

## Problem

I want to use *Visual Studio Emulator for Android* but whenever I try to start it it fails.

[image]

The final part of the Log is:

```
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] ===== Session Started =====
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0 Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] Virtualization Version: alaska - 1072009
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: to be filled by o.e.m.
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] Virtualization Product: z97-d3h-cf
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960, Version: 10.18.13.5362
27.9.2015. 11:10:38: [Informational] Display Adapter 1: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600, Version: 10.18.14.4170
27.9.2015. 11:10:39: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
27.9.2015. 11:10:39: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 3 Platforms: 2
27.9.2015. 11:10:39: [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
27.9.2015. 11:10:39: [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices:     30 Platforms: 4
27.9.2015. 11:10:41: [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
27.9.2015. 11:10:41: [Informational] Launching Device: 10.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet
27.9.2015. 11:10:41: [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
27.9.2015. 11:10:41: [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
27.9.2015. 11:10:41: [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
27.9.2015. 11:10:47: [Critical] An internal virtual network switch is required for emulated devices to run.
27.9.2015. 11:10:47: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
27.9.2015. 11:10:47: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 10.1\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 10.1 /video "2560x1600" /vhd "C:\Users\Miro\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\10.1_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XHDPI_Tablet\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 10.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet.miro" /noStart /silent
27.9.2015. 11:10:47: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: CouldntCreateInternalSwitch (16)
```

## So far I've tried...

1. Done all steps from [How to enable Hyper-V for the emulator for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx)

   - *VMX* and *EPT* are enabled - checked with *coreinfo.exe*
   - *SLAT* is enabled - checked with *CheckSLATStatusOfMachine.exe*
   - Disabled *Intel VT-d*
   - Enabled *Hyper-V* in *Windows features*
2. After all the relevant changes I've unpluged PC from power supply and tried again
3. Repaired *Visual Studio Emulator for Android* and run *XdeCleanup.exe*
4. Disabled *Kaspersky Internet Security*
   (I've read that sometimes security software interfere)
5. Checked if I'm member of the *Hyper-V Administrators group*
6. Successfully created and started new VM directly in *Hyper-V Manager*
   (This was just to check could I run any VM)

## System info

- CPU: [Intel i7-4790K](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz)
- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center
- Hyper-V Manager: v6.3.9600.16384

## Comment

I've spent a lot of time to figure out the solution and I've failed. What am I missing?

I saw that for Windows phone sometimes they set their own virtual switch in *Hyper-V Manager*. Is that something I should also do, and how should it be done?

### Edit #1

In the meantime:

1. I manually added private and internal switch networks (named "Windows Phone Emulator Private Switch" and "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch", if naming matters). Restarted afterwards, tried again. Didn't work.
2. I've noticed that *XdeCleanup.exe* deletes manually created internal private switch.
   [image]

### Edit #2

I've tired method suggested by @John Kemnetz.The emulator environment starts.

[image]
After selecting *Yes* this exception is shown.
[image]

## Edit #3 :: Solution ☺ ::

I've came to the second attempt suggested by @John Kemnetz in later answer.
These are all the steps:

1. Opened *Device Manager* and deleted one and only *Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V* from *Network adapters*
2. Then I couldn't find *Network adapters* at all, it disappeared so I couldn't reinstall network driver
3. After I had rebooted machine not only *Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V* was installed automatically in *Network adapters* but also *Microsoft Hyper-V Network Switch Default Miniport* was installed. Something that I saw for the first time.
   [image]
4. Then I tried the same console entry as in Edit #2. The console didn't started as in Edit #2. Instead I got this.
   [image]
   Well at least there was no error!
5. So I ran strait to VS2015, created Cordova app from template and tried to run emulator. After I gave all the requested user privileges it successfully started!
6. Then I saw under *Network adapters* two new entries that were created automatically in process.
   [image]

Comment: Had the same problem and deleting the Adapter via device manager and all Hyper-V virtual switches and android virtual machines and then rebooting (auto-reinstalling a load of other adapters) was the solution! Thanks for sharing this @JohnKemnetz ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a problem with Hyper-V. You may want to try the following (in order):*

1. Open Hyper-V Manager, delete all virtual switches via the Virtual Switch Manager, delete all VMs, and reboot. Now, try to restart the emulator.
2. If that also fails, attempt to upgrade your drivers for the adapter connecting you to the internet (I'm guessing it's a WiFi adapter?). Go to Control Panel > Device Manager and under "Network Adapters" find your WiFi/internet adapter, right click, and uninstall. When done, right click on Network adapters and scan for hardware changes. This will reinstall your adapter. Reboot, then try to start the emulator again.
3. If that still fails, the last course of action is to run a "repair" on Windows. If there truly is a problem between Hyper-V and your network adapters, this may resolve the issue

*note that #2 was the solution that worked for kr85

Comment: Are you missing the rest of text? Your last sentence ends with "..., this may"

Comment: Ah sorry, looks like it posted before I was done with that sentence. Fixed now.

Comment: I also had to make sure my current user account was a member of the Hyper-V Administrators AND THEN REBOOT MY COMPUTER or the same thing will occur.  Deleting virtual switches of type Internal helped also.  Deleting all VMs appears not to be needed, at least in my case.

Comment: Allowing Visual Studio to create the emulator's internet connection screwed up my normal internet connection. and the solution was to reset all my internet connections.  this is a giant pain if I'm going to have to go through this process every time I want to debug an android app on my pc.

Answer (score 2):

In the log file you've got:

```
27.9.2015. 11:10:47: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
27.9.2015. 11:10:47: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 10.1\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 10.1 /video "2560x1600" /vhd "C:\Users\Miro\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\10.1_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XHDPI_Tablet\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 10.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet.miro" /noStart /silent
```

If you run that command manually in Command Prompt, but without the /noStart and /silent flags, it will tell you why it can't create the virtual switch.

Comment: I have a laptop with win10, and I had problems with emulating android devices, but the other parts of the problem was the same. That worked for me running the command as **administrator** (maybe it is not solution for the original problem, I tried this first). After selecting _Yes_ there was no exception, the emulator and the emulated os started as excepted.

Comment: I've also tried running the command as administrator but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

This error took me weeks to finally resolve. The above solutions did not work for me when doing only what was mentioned. Finally I did all of the following which resolved my issue.

1. Closed all EXD.exe in task manager.
2. Exported and then deleted all VMs in Hyper-V.
3. Deleted all Network Switches in Hyper-V (except the default which would not delete).
4. Deleted my Network Adapters, restarted (it recreated all of them automatically).
5. Went to Add Remove Program > Selected Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android > Clicked Modify > Clicked Repair.
6. Ran XdeCleanup.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.15063.0.
7. Went to Network Connections and disabled all unnecessary connections.

Installed the Emulator again and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3)

Follow the steps in above URL, it's also doesn't work.

Then I do the steps below, it's work!

1. Uninstall all net work adapter in device manager, reboot computer.
2. Open Visual Studio Emulator for Android, click "Uninstall profile" of the device you want to lunch, then click "Install profile" to reinstall it. Now, lunch the device, it should work.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade the network adapter drivers (I didn't even need to uninstall it) and restart the computer