# Couldnt Create Internal Switch Android Emulator error

Tags: android, emulation

I have been try to get the Visual Studio Android Emulator working, but, every time i try to launch the emulator this error code seems to stop it: CouldntCreateInternalSwitch. I have uninstalled all other Internal switches (such as Virtual Box) and created a new Internal switch for the emulator but this error still outputs. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the programming problem here?

Comment: Programming problem? I'm just trying to get the Emulator working. And it gives me error CouldntCreateInternalSwitch

Comment: In Stackoverflow, you are allowed to ask anything related to programming where you are stacked. But you have to show your effort and make sure you have googled it enough. Then it would be treated as a good question. @Jordan

Comment: I have googled it and done everything I found. Nothing worked. I found other articles about this on here that didn't help me so i posted my own.

Comment: An "Internal Switch" is a construct of MS Windows' Hyper-V hypervisor which is apparently used by VirtualBox, which hosts the Android Emulator.
So, this isn't a programming question. You probably want to ask over at one of the other Stack Exchange sites - probably either http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807505/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-an-internal-virtual-network-switch-is-requi