# Visual studio android emulator asks for the internet, but it kills my own internet on my pc

Tags: visual-studio, networking, android-emulator, windows-10

When I try to open visual studio android emulator it asks me to let it use the internet but when i do my pc loses internet connection. but when i refuse it just fails to start. how can i let it use internet while I keep my internet on my pc as well?
[image: Alert message after trying to start emulator]

and it really kills my internet

please help me if you know about this issue

Answer (score 0):

That may be the issue with the misconfiguration and Hyper-V. Se [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807505/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-an-internal-virtual-network-switch-is-requi) for the possible answer. Basically, it uses Hyper-V for emulation, and virtual network switch is needed for providing the internet access for the device. Sometimes, something mixed up and that switch becomes the issue for the launching the emulator.