# I can't debug android sample app in visual studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I just installed visual studio 2015 with Xamarin. I created Android blank app (c#), when I run debug I get error message :

```
1>Starting deploy 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Starting emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Validating emulator arguments...
1>Determining if emulator is already running...
1>Preparing virtual machine...
1>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
1>An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' device.
1>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
1>An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' device.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't know what happen, someone can help me please?

Thank you for your time

Comment: "An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details" Well, have you checked the log? "Visual Studio -> Help -> Xamarin -> Logs" (or something like that)

Comment: Here is error log but I don't understand too much on it http://pastebin.com/t76iaKpU

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3