# Building app with Cordova using Visual studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-cordova, hyper-v

I am using visual studio to develop cordova apps, they seem to run perfectly on ripple emulator but when I select GOOGLE ANDROID EMULATOR then it gives the error as 
`THIS AVD's CONFIGURATION IS MISSING A KERNEL FILE`

and when I use VS EMULATOR 5'' KITKAT(4.4) XXHDPI PHONE then it gives the error as `YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO MODIFY HYPER-V NETWORK ADAPTER SETTINGS`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you try running VS as administrator and start KitKat Emulator again?

Comment: Hi Elvis,
Thanks for the quick response. I tried running visual studio as administrator and tried starting kitkat emulator same as mentioned above the one again. But it gave AN ERROR OCCURED WHILE CREATING THE VS EMULATOR 5" KITKAT (4.4) XXHDPI PHONE DEVICE. That is all the error message gave me. Could you please help?

Comment: There is a similar case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3), could you try the steps of the answer? Please let me know if the problem persists or solved.

Comment: Hi Elvis,
Can you explain the fourth step of the answer. As I am not able to go over the step where it says in the output log PREPARING VIRTUAL MACHINE. I think I am making some error in step 4.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an incomplete install of the Google Android Emulator and have to install one yourself.

Download Android Studio, open the SDK manager, and install the following components:

- latest "Android SDK tools"
- latest "Android SDK platform-tools"
- latest "Android SDK build-tools"
- Android 6.0 API 23 - SDK platform  -- to build the latest kind of Android app
- Android 5.0.1 API 21 - SDK platform -- to use the emulator successfully
- Android 5.0.1 API 21 - ARM EaBI v7a System Image -- the emulator image which you can use on a machine with Hyper V activated

Then, open the AVD manager and create an emulator with the ARM system image.

Finally, go to tools->options->"Tools for Apache Cordova" -> Environmental variable overrides, and link to where your customized Android Studio is installed.