# Visual Studio Emulator For Android don't work

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin

[image]

Hi

I have installed Visual Studio Emulator for android and trying to install Device profile, in my case 5 KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone, but as you see the installation froze.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: It has been installed finally, but can not launch. This type of error occured:
**An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' device. XDE Path: C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe XDE Arguments:/sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" KitKat (4.4)XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5 /video "1080x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_KitKat_(4.4)XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone" /noStart /silent. InvalidArguments (3)**

Comment: Instead of commenting, edit your post with these relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

There's a complete troubleshooting page on Microsoft's documentation for the emulator:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx

However I would recommend posting the full log in your question so it's easier to diagnose. Given a quick search, it seems to be a duplicate of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31698124/1048571

Comment: I did it like this links, but same problem. I just checked Hyper V manger and some kind of reason, there are not any virtual machines

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Hyper V manager and select the simulator that you want to run and right click -> settings -> Processor -> Compatibility over there make sure “Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version” is checked

Comment: There are not any simulators, virtual machines or virtual switches in Hyper V manager, why? I don't know.