# Visual studio emulator for android Stuck at Copying .vhd files

Tags: android, windows-10, emulation, visual-studio-emulator

I had the emulator running once and had to remove it because I had to work with virtualBox as you cannot run hyper-v and virtual box together.

As I had the emulator running, it means that my system is compatible. I am running windows 10 with i7 processor.

The installation process went smooth but when I tried to create a virtual device the process gets stuck at

```
 Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine
```

I tried following the steps shown here [Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3)

But It does not work.

what is the way where I can completely remove everything and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to start from scratch, my suggestion would be, make a backup of projects, uninstall VS 15, uninstall emulator, uninstall other plug-in, clear temp, restart, then install again. Quite a long process, which is anyway should not be recommended.