# Use Visual studio emulator for android as standalone

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

Is it possible to use the Visual studio emulator for android as a stand alone android emulator without Visual studio IDE.

I am having trouble getting it up and running.

Facing issues such as these:

[Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3)

[Visual studio emulator for android Stuck at Copying .vhd files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054922/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-stuck-at-copying-vhd-files)

Answer (score 0):

you can download standalone install [here](https://aka.ms/vscomemudownload) and find more information on its from : https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Regards,
AP

Comment: Will I need hyper-v for this? Can this work alongside with Virtual box?

Comment: its work with Virtual box, also verify that hyper-v is turn off in windows.