# Installing Emulator gets stuck on "Preparing Virtual Machine"

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, emulation, hyper-v

I've installed VS Emulator for Android which was successful. But when I try to install the device it gets stuck on "Preparing Virtual Machine". Before that, the VS Emulator for Android asks to be run on Elevated mode showing the issue below.

I also attached the screenshot of my Virtual switches in Hyper-v Manager, does it have any issue? I'm not quite familiar with Hyper V Manager.

[Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3/31698124#31698124) 
      This answer also didn't help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you manage it to fix it?