# Xamarin android emulator stuck at "Preparing virtual machine..."

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android, emulation

I wanted to get into Xamarin, but I have a problem. Whenever I try to run any of the settings in Android emulator , the warning "You do not have permission to modify internal Hyper-V network adapter settings" pop-up. Since I have the admin rights, I just click "Retry"(with admin rights). However, after I click the "Retry" button, the emulator gets stuck at "Preparing virtual machine..." .

I've rebooted, reinstalled the emulator, and made sure that Hyper-v was on, yet the problem persists.

I've found a very similar question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542053/installing-emulator-gets-stuck-on-preparing-virtual-machine), but this question has no answers.
How can I get the emulator to run? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am trying to use Visual studio emulator for Android

Comment: Can you please state what emulator you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use GenyMotion emulator, it's work fast and based on VirtualBox VM. But to use Genymotion, you must disable Hyper-V.

To switch Hyper-V on or off on a Windows computer, you can refer to the article - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx